# preg_replace - how to escape "["

Tags: preg-replace

I wrote this code:

```
<?
$text='how are you [b] today [/b]';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\[b/';
$patterns[1] = '/\b]/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = 'b]aaa<>';
$replacements[0] = '<>aaa[b';


ksort($patterns);
ksort($replacements);
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
echo "_";
echo $text;
echo "_";
echo "END";

?>
```

the output shows:

```
how are you <>aaa[bb]aaa<> today [/b]aaa<>______how are you [b] today [/b]______END
```

but the output should be:

```
how are you <>aaa[b] today [/b]aaa<>______how are you [b] today [/b]______END
```

what did I do wrong? Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-escape the brackets:

```
$patterns[0] = '/\\[b/';
```

A single backslash will be "consumed" by PHP when it parses the string, leaving just a bare `[`, which will be seen by the regex engine as the beginning of a character class. By double-escaping, the `\\` will be seen by PHP as an escape, leaving a single `\`, which will be seen by the regex engine as an escape.

Comment: thanks for fast response!
I changed to:
$patterns[0] = '/\\[b/';
$patterns[1] = '/\\b]/';
but the result is the same...? how are you <>aaa[bb]aaa<> today [/bb]aaa<>______how are you [b] today [/b]______END

Comment: im trying to covert (or better "append") <span class="notranslate"> to "[b" and </span> to "b]" so google translate will not translate bbcode.

Comment: is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello. I have found the function strtr easier. You can easily escape regexs with "\" in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with escaping `[`. Your problem is that you want `$patterns[1]` to only match "/b]" but that's not what you wrote in your regular expression.

Try `'/\/b]/'` instead, or use alternate delimiters (e.g. `'!/b]!'`) to avoid leaning-toothpick syndrome.

Comment: if I use: $patterns[0] = '/\/b]/';
$patterns[1] = '/\/[b/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = 'b]aaa<>';
$replacements[0] = '<>aaa[b'; I get "Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 4 in "

Comment: @tej: Why did you change both patterns, and switch around which is which at the same time?

Comment: Im sorry i'm confused :P what do you mean?

Comment: oh I see what I did. this is the right code:  <?
$text='how are you [b] today [/b]';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '!b]!';
$patterns[1] = '![b!';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = '<>aaa[b';
$replacements[0] = 'b]aaa<>';
 

ksort($patterns);
ksort($replacements);
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
echo "______";
echo $text;
echo "______";
echo "END";

?>

Comment: it is still the same error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 2 in

Comment: is there a simpler way to do this?